# Подключение плагина к созданным элементам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте,

Если на странице есть элемент, к которому привязывается плагин jQuery (например select2), то плагин работает. Если элемент создается скриптом, то плагин к нему не привязывается. Как подключать плагины к динамично создающимся элементам? (В примере нажатие на кнопку "add select" создает новый выпадающий список, но к нему не подключается плагин)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").select2();
  $("input[type=button]").on('click',function(){
    $("div").append('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select>');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Add select"/>
  <br/>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну так и выполните плагин для вновь созданного элемента (селектор `div` слегка слишком общий кстати, сделайте с этим что нибудь)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").select2();
  $("input[type=button]").on('click',function(){
    $('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select>')
       .appendTo('div').select2();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Add select"/>
  <br/>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Cелектор div только для примера, там он один:) А есть способы сделать это иначе? У меня вместе с select приходит еще много другого кода разметки (AJAX). Ищу что-то вроде `$(docunent).on('change' function(){...});` что бы 1 раз написать и при всех изменениях плагин подключался к select'ам

Comment: нет, т.е. есть но это тормозно (следить за DOM тормозно, да и не везде работает),  сделайте так примерно, 
`$(<div><select></select></div>).appendTo(myPlace).find('select').select2()`

Comment: Попробовал `.bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){});` Это действительно плохо (хром долго думал и крашнул страницу). Спасибо, буду делать что-то в вашем стиле